# Calculate the inverse of a non-square matrix using numpy

Tags: numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

Is there a way where I can calculate the inverse of a mxn non-square matrix using numpy? Since using `la.inv(S)` seems to give me an error of `ValueError: expected square matrix`

Comment: A non-square matrix does not have an inverse. If you are looking for a pseudo-inverse, you will need to specify what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: Yeah sorry I'm trying to calculate the pseudo-inverse of a matrix A using 'A_inv = P*S_inv*Q^T'

Answer (score 9):

You are probably looking for [`np.linalg.pinv`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.pinv.html).

### EDIT 23-08-12:

Alaboration: pinv (psaudu-inverse) computes the Moore–Penrose pseudo inverse of a matrix using its SVD, when the matrix is non invertible ( thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/774575/mins )

Comment: ... which computes the [Moore–Penrose pseudo inverse of a matrix](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/moore-penrose-pseudoinverse/) using its SVD, when the matrix is non invertible.

Answer (score 2):

To calculate the non square matrix mxn, We can use np.linalg.pinv(S), here s is the data you want to pass.

For square matrix we use np.linalg.inv(S), The inverse of a matrix is such that if it is multiplied by the original matrix, it results in identity matrix.

note: np is numpy

We can also use np.linalg.inv(S) for non square matrix but in order to not get any error you need to slice the data S.

For more details on np.linalg.pinv : https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.pinv.html

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.